# can tcl package compiled to dll on windows?

Tags: windows, dll, tcl

i know that tcl code can be used to crate packages for reuse.i encountered a tcl package in "dll" format(**the package is being used with the `package require` command with `auto_path`, not the `load` command** ).

but i searched on the web and only find tcl package that lives as a tcl script file or as an tcl extension(to be used with the `load` method)

1. is it possible to create tcl package in dll format(possible using other language)?
2. if the dll file is created in tcl language, can i extract the code in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages in Tcl are strictly a high-level concept that abstracts away from how the bundle of functionality is implemented. When you say `package require foo`, the package manager goes away and looks up how to actually get the package in, and makes it available to you.

So how are they implemented? The core ideas are that there's an index file in a specific format, and that describes a bunch of things to do, usually using `source` to get scripts in and `load` to get DLLs in. Which does a package actually use? Depends on the package. (There are also ways for a package to be done without an index file at all, but Tcl Modules are a rather more complex topic in other ways.)

But if all you've actually got is the DLL, you can just `load` it directly. Use the absolute pathname to the file when you do this; names without directory separators in work differently for historical reasons (they invoke the system library discovery mechanism, which you don't need if you *know* which file it is).

```
# Any form that Tcl understands filenames in will do; I use / because it isn't a quote char
load C:/the/path/to/the/library.dll
```

That's all that you actually need to do. The only advantage with getting a package properly installed with its index file is to make your scripts portable to somewhere with different installation locations (and to give you the chance to describe the package versioning requirement). Which is convenient, but not critical for stuff you're doing for yourself.

---

So, how could it have got there? Well, Tcl doesn't actually care too much. As long as the DLL contains the right entry point function (name depends on the dll name; for `frobnicate.dll` it would look for `Frobnicate_Init`; this is overrideable) it will work. The usual languages for making them are C and C++, but anything that can make the right function will work. It's a bit difficult with languages that require a complex runtime to operate, but that's up to you.

There are a few tools that could generate a DLL from Tcl code, but they're usually not intended to make it easy to extract the code, either because they are deliberate obfuscators or because  (in one case, which I'm working on) they are converting Tcl code to machine code; there is no source left to extract. On the other hand, there are ways to package code so that it is just contained in a DLL so maybe that is what happened here. All you can do for extracting really is to pop the code into a tool to extract the strings from inside the binary code (the Unix `strings` utility would be ideal for this) and see if there is something likely-looking; there probably isn't but you might get lucky.

Disassembling a fairly arbitrary DLL is going to be unpleasant. It's going to be especially annoying if it is a Tcl Stubs enabled DLL, as that replaces calls to Tcl's API (useful to know about when disassembling!) with indirect calls via an API reference handler, which looks *really* confusing at the disassembly level.

If you're really asking this question because you're thinking about ways to package your own code so that users don't pick it apart, there's a commercial tool (the TclDevKit from ActiveState) that can do a decent job of it. It's good enough to defeat all but the most extremely determined. I don't use it myself as I don't distribute obfuscated code, but I know of many other people who recommend it.